# Preg_replace Template replacement which doesn't cause undefined index errors

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a template which has certain fields which are to be replaced with a given value.

The fields each have a name which is enclosed with curly brackets.  For instance: {address}
The replacement values are included in an array where the index is the name. For instance `array('address'=>'101 Main Street', 'city’=>'New York')`

I am using the following, and it works great (most of the time)

```
$template_new= preg_replace('/\{\?(\w+)\?\}/e', '$array["$1"]', $template);
```

Problem is if I have a `{bad_name}` which is not in the array, I get the following error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: xxx in
>   **/var/www/classes/library.php(860) : regexp code** on line
>   **1**

My desire is to leave these in place without changing them.

My first thought was to replace `$array["$1"]` with `(isset($array["$1"])?$array["$1"]': '{'.$1.'}')`, but it didn’t work.

I also tried try/catch, but it also didn’t help

Please provide any recommendations.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have better luck with [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and doing something like this:

```
<?php
class Substitute {

    public function __construct($template) {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->values = array();
    }

    public function run($values) {
        $this->values = $values;
        return preg_replace_callback('/\{\?(\w+)\?\}/', array($this, 'subst'), $this->template);
    }

    private function subst($matches) {
        if (isset($this->values[$matches[1]])) {
            return $this->values[$matches[1]];
        }
        // Don't bother doing the substitution.
        return $matches[0];
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, I typed that in off the top of my head, so there may be bugs.

Here's how you'd do much the same thing with anonymous functions, assuming you're able to use them:

```
function substitute($template, $values) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\{\?(\w+)\?\}/',
        function ($matches) use ($values) {
            if (isset($values[$matches[1]])) {
                return $values[$matches[1]];
            }
            // Don't bother doing the substitution.
            return $matches[0];
        },
        $template);
}
```

Much more compact!

Comment: Thanks Keith,  Let me try it out when I get home.

Comment: Still haven't tested it, but I like it.  I've always hated that /e modifier, and now I see it has been depreciated :)  I currently do not have any experience with PHP anonymous functions, but I think it might be a good application.

Comment: Yup, you could use it with anonymous functions. In fact, if you look at the docs, using them with `preg_replace_callback()` is even the first example provided. They're an ideal case for them, and, if I knew which version of PHP 5 you were using, I would've used them in my example rather than a class, which, frankly, makes using the `preg_replace_callback()` somewhat clumsy.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  Works perfect except that uses should be use.  But not bad for doing off the top of your head!

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that, though I've fixed it now.